# How do I convert a list with graphical links to an inline list?

Tags: html, css

Given this HTML:

```
<ul id="topnav">
    <li id="topnav_galleries"><a href="#">Galleries</a></li>
    <li id="topnav_information"><a href="#">Information</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS:

```css
#topnav_galleries a, #topnav_information a {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 46px;
    width: 136px;
    display: block;
}
#topnav { list-style-type: none; }
#topnav_galleries a { background-image: url('image1.jpg'); }
#topnav_information a { background-image: url('image2.jpg'); }
```

How would I go about turning the `topnav` list into an inline list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#topnav {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#topnav li {
    float:left;
}
```

And for IE you will need to add the following:

```css
#topnav {
    zoom:1;
}
```

Otherwise your floated < li > tags will spill out of the containing < ul >.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to floating the elements left, is this:

```css
#topnav li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `display: inline-block` for `li` s:

```
#topnav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```